# javascript change input value by link title

Tags: javascript, input, default-value

I'm new to JavaScript and I need some help with a simple problem I'm having:

I have one empty input field, and two links (`anchors`) with differing values for the `title` attribute.

I'd like to write a small piece of JavaScript that changes the value of the `input` element to the title of whichever link the user clicks.

For example:

First link = `Prague`
Second link = `Budapest`

When I click "Budapest" I'd like the value of the `input` element to change to "Budapest"

If needed I can supply a basic `jsFiddle` but hopefully I've made myself clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project is really this small then it's probably easier to just attach some `onclick` handlers to your anchors, and then define a very basic function to update the input element.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" title="Prague" onclick="updateValue(this.title, event);">Prague</a>
<a href="#" title="Budapest" onclick="updateValue(this.title, event);">Budapest</a>
<input type="text" id="country" name="country" value="" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function updateValue(val, event) {
    document.getElementById("country").value = val;
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zUVA5/

If you have a large amount of anchors then adding individual `onclick` handlers by hand would be quite a pain, to avoid this you can simply wrap your content in a containing element and then apply `click` event handlers to all nested anchors programmatically:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FUvYC/

Answer (score 1):

The process would be to find all of the anchors, then attach a click handler which sets the input value to the clicked anchor's `title` attribute. The example below finds all anchors on the page, but you might prefer to add a class and use `document.querySelectorAll()` (which is not fully supported by old IE).

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aSHUC/)**

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="" />
<a href="#" title="Prague">Prague link</a>
<a href="#" title="Budapest">Budapest link</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
        anchors[i].onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById("myinput").value = this.getAttribute("title");
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't believe in cluttering answers with `window.onload` etc style hooks, unless they're directly relevant to the question.

Comment: It depends on the question, in this particular question I felt it's relevant to be explicit to avoid further comments troubleshooting the problem if OP failed to include a DOM ready wrapper.

Comment: fair point, except that there are hundreds of other questions here that already address that specific problem.  Also, if the OP followed "best practise" and put their code at the end of the body tag they wouldn't need to use an event handler at all.

Comment: In my experience, someone at this level would typically seek clarification from the answer author if it doesn't work, especially in this case where failure to include a DOM ready wrapper, will not produce any errors to follow up on. Also the "best practice" of generally putting scripts at the end of the body tag relates to external script downloads or scripts that download other external files, not necessarily embedded JavaScript. Plus not everyone agrees that is best practice anyway, look at the StackOverflow source for one, but anyway that is getting way off topic to this question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Budapest" onclick="changeTitle('Budapest')">Budapest</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Prague" onclick="changeTitle('Prague ')">Prague       
</a>

<input type="text" id="test"/>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function changeTitle(changeVal){
  var link_text = $('#'+changeVal).text();
  $("#test").val(link_text);   
}
</script>
```