# JavaScript change input value via link

Tags: javascript

I have a foreach function which listing all members of array. I want that member of array is a link which change input value.

I have function for reading input like this

```
<input type="text" id="syote" name="syote" value="" />
<button id="myBtn" onclick="submitti()">Submit</button>
```

```
function submitti(){

let current ="syote"

var txt = ""

    let array2 = [
    'soita',
    'sammuta',
    'google',
    'listaa',
    'oskari',
    'tee popup',
    '10',
    'input alas',
    'input ylös',
    'värillinen',
    'mustavalkoinen',
    'kysely'
    ]

if(syote.value.toLowerCase() == "listaaa"){
        document.getElementById("vas-col").className = "vasen";

        array2.forEach(myFunction);
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = txt;

        function myFunction(value, array2) {
        txt = txt + "<a href=# onclick=Muuta()>" + value + "</a>" + "<br>"; 

        }
    }
```

```
function Muuta(value) {
    input.value = "asdasdasd";
}
```

This is working and it change input value to **asdasdasd**.

I want it change input value same than member of array list.

I tried these without succes:

```
function myFunction(value, array2) {
        txt = txt + "<a href=# onclick=Muuta(value)>" + value + "</a>" + "<br>";

function Muuta(value) {
    input.value = value;
}
```

```
function myFunction(value, array2) {
        txt = txt + "<a href=# title=value onclick=Muuta(this.title)>" + value + "</a>" + "<br>";

function Muuta(value) {
    input.value = value;
}
```

Found some examples also and not working in my case. Like this: [javascript change input value by link title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671966/javascript-change-input-value-by-link-title)

Comment: Anyone? I can not find solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours i find solution for this problem.

With this it works:

```
    if(syote.value.toLowerCase() == "listaa"){

        // Näissä kohdissa missä id:ssä on väliviiva täytyy käyttää edessä document.getElementById. Ilman sitä ei muuta classia ja näin ollen scroll ei ilmesty.
        document.getElementById("vas-col").className = "vasen scroll";

        array.forEach(ListaaKomennot);
        result1.innerHTML = txt;

        function ListaaKomennot(value, array) {
        txt = txt + "<a href='#' title='" + value + "' onclick='MuutaArvo(this.title);'>" + value + "</a>" + "<br>"; 
        }
    }
```

```
function MuutaArvo(arvo) {
    syote.value = arvo;
}
```

In title is very important to be `'` before `"` and same vice versa after value. Without `' '` it cuts out after whitespace when change value of input to title. If you have only words without whitespace that is not a problem.

It is best to solve yourself, i learned many new things at same time. Inter alia if your html id name is with `-` tag like i have in `oik-col` you must use document.getElementById without it, className won't work.